# Custom cast not applied to references of derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, casting, reference

When casting references, it seems that the compiler tries to convert the `Derived` class to its `Base` and does not use the custom cast at all. This works flawlessly with pointers though.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    int fn() {
        return 42;
    }
};

class Derived : private Base {
public:
    operator Base&() {
        return *dynamic_cast<Base*>(this);
    }

    operator Base*() {
        return dynamic_cast<Base*>(this);
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    Derived &dRef = d;

    std::cout<<static_cast<Base&>(dRef).fn()<<std::endl;    // <-- error: non-reachable base >>Base<< of >>Derived<<
    std::cout<<static_cast<Base*>(d)->fn()<<std::endl;      // OK -> "42"
}
```

Why is it not possible to use the custom cast like this? Is it possible to achieve the intended behavior ("upcasting" to a non-reachable base with references)?

Comment: You'll notice your base class is *private* intentionally, yes?

Comment: @WhozCraig that's intended, therefore we need the cast. It does work with pointers though.

Comment: Well, the former (the reference) would never be called anyway, and your compiler should have warned you about it: clang, for example: "Conversion function converting 'Derived' to its base class 'Base' will never be used".

Comment: I am trying to understand why it is possible to cast it using the pointer but not using the reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[class.conv.fct]/1 reads (emphasis mine):

> A conversion function is never used to convert a (possibly cv-qualified) object to the (possibly cv-qualified)
>   same object type (or a reference to it), to a (possibly cv-qualified) **base class of that type (or a reference to
>   it)**, or to (possibly cv-qualified) void.

And indeed clang gives a warning:

```
warning: conversion function converting 'Derived' to its base class 'Base' will never be used
operator Base&() {
^
```

There's no such restriction for pointers, so `static_cast<Base*>(d)` works and calls the custom conversion operator.

If you really want to use the conversion operator for references, you have to call it explicitly:

```
std::cout << dRef.operator Base&().fn() << std::endl;
```

But in this case you'll probably want to create just a regular member function for that, or be honest and just make the inheritance public.

Comment: Or use composition for reuse, instead of inheritance.